# is this configuration correct?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I try to configure an apache load balancer to manage how server status becomes error and how the server status becomes OK. The apache version is 2.4 .

I understood that a server state is error when a request received serveral timeouts. The timeout value is defined by the balancer member parameter timeout and the number of tries is defined by the balancer parameter maxattempts. see [proxy parameter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass).

Is that right ?

Now to manage more precisely how a server is set as in error, i want to use :

- failonstatus parameter to define for which http codes a server is set in error
- retry to define the time between two connections tries

To check more precisely server status, i would like to use the module mod_proxy_hcheck. see [mod_proxy_check](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html).

My target configuration is :

```
ProxyHCExpr ok2 {%{REQUEST_STATUS} =~ /^[2]/}
<Proxy balancer://anUrl>
    BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=1 timeout=30 retry=12  hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok2 hcinterval=10 hcpasses=2
    BalancerMember http://server2:8080 route=2 timeout=30 retry=12  hcmethod=HEAD hcexpr=ok2 hcinterval=10 hcpasses=2
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness maxattempts=2 failonstatus=500,501,502,503
</Proxy>
```

With a such configuration :

- request scheduling/balancing depends on the number of pending requests of servers see [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)
- if an http request code is one of 500,501,502,503 the balancer member/worker/server is set in error
- if a request takes more 30 seconde two times with 12 seconds between each try , the balancer member/worker/server is set in error
- if a head request on / returns two times a code different than 2XX with 10 seconds between each try, the balancer member/worker/server is set in error
- when a server is in error, Apache waits 12 seconds before to send a request to it again and to change the server status if the request is successfull

Is that right ?

A last question, if apache detects that a server is in error when a request received serveral timeouts, why is there the failontimeout parameter ?